# dtreevizを使って決定木を作ろうとしたがエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, graphviz, dtreeviz

下記のプログラムをVSCodeのJupyter Notebookで実行しようとしたが、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

dtreeviz,pyGraphvizもダウンロードしており、graphvizもダウンロード・pathも通しております
graphvizはversion 8.0.5です。
dtreevizはversion 2.2.1です。
アドバイスを頂けるとありがたいです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
C:\Users\jy132\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23164\404471695.py:4: DeprecationWarning: dtreeviz() function is deprecated starting from version 2.0. 
 For the same functionality, please use this code instead: 
 m = dtreeviz.model(...) 
 m.view()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 4
      1 # ライブラリのインポート
      2 from dtreeviz import *
----> 4 viz = dtreeviz(clf, df_x, df['inf1b'], 
      5                feature_names = df_x.columns,
      6                target_name='メディアの使用頻度',
      7                #class_names = list(data_target_names),
      8                )
     10 display(viz)

File c:\Users\jy132\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\compatibility.py:254, in dtreeviz(tree_model, X_train, y_train, feature_names, target_name, class_names, tree_index, precision, orientation, instance_orientation, show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, highlight_path, X, max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize, fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)
    251 shadow_tree = ShadowDecTree.get_shadow_tree(tree_model, X_train, y_train, feature_names, target_name, class_names,
    252                                             tree_index)
    253 model = DTreeVizAPI(shadow_tree)
--> 254 return model.view(precision, orientation,
    255                   instance_orientation,
    256                   show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, highlight_path, X,
    257                   max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize,
    258                   fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors=colors, scale=scale)

File c:\Users\jy132\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\trees.py:519, in DTreeVizAPI.view(self, precision, orientation, instance_orientation, show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, leaftype, highlight_path, x, max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize, fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)
    517 tmp = tempfile.gettempdir()
    518 if x is not None:
...
--> 335 if self.shouldGoLeftAtSplit(t.id, x[t.feature()]):
    336     return walk(t.left, x, path)
    337 return walk(t.right, x, path)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**ソースコード:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import japanize_matplotlib
#import pydot

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics, tree

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('ds1.csv'))
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[0])
df.head()

Col_x=["B_sub","ni_f","rcv_f","s","political","age"]
df_x = df[Col_x]
df_y = df["inf1b"]

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, random_state=1, test_size=0.15)

# モデルの作成
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3) 

# モデルの学習
clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

# 評価
clf.score(train_x, train_y)

clf.score(test_x, test_y)


# ライブラリのインポート
from dtreeviz import *
#ここの部分をimport dtreevizに変更　

viz = dtreeviz(clf, df_x, df['inf1b'], 
               feature_names = df_x.columns,
               target_name='メディアの使用頻度',
               #class_names = list(data_target_names),
               )

display(viz)
#上記の部分を以下のように変更したら正常に動作した。

viz = dtreeviz.model(clf, 
                     X_train=df_x,
                     y_train=df['inf1b'],
                     feature_names = df_x.columns,
                     target_name='Media usage frequency',
                     class_names=["don't use much","Neither","use much"]
               )

viz.view()
```

Comment: https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz のサンプルコードは動きますか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます
どのコードが動けばいいでしょうか？

Comment: Exampleのコードのことです。

Comment: Classification tree on iris dataを実行したところ, <br>
'NameError: name 'dtreeviz' is not defined'というエラーがでました

Comment: GoogleColaboratoryではTypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptableというエラーがでました

Comment: 回答に付いたコメントで補足されていますが、質問に提示するソースコードは不足等の無い完結したものを提示(またコメントで補足するのではなく記事を編集して追記して)してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 「<br> 'NameError: name 'dtreeviz' is not defined'というエラーがでました」とのことですが、「import dtreeviz」の実行を忘れてませんか？

Comment: 「GoogleColaboratoryではTypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptableというエラーがでました –」とのことですが、当方では再現しません。エラーについてはコードの”どの部分”で発生したか？が重要ですのでエラーメッセージと合わせて情報を記入してください。

Comment: https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz のサンプルコード(Example)も動作しないとなると、質問者さんのデータセット以前の問題のような気がします。まずは簡単なデータで動作するようにした方が良いかと思います。

Comment: @merino  自分が実行していたファイルが異なっていたかもしれないです。github.com\parrt\dtreeviz-master\notebooks\dtreeviz_sklearn_pipeline_visualisations.ipynbを実行したところ、正常に出力されました。

Comment: @merino
github.com\parrt\dtreeviz\dtreeviz-master\notebooks\dtreeviz_sklearn_visualisations.ipynbを参考にしてコードを少しいじったら出力されるようになりました。

Answer (score 1):

merimoさんが提示してくださった [GitHub リポジトリ](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/) の [dtreeviz_sklearn_visualisations.ipynb](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/notebooks/dtreeviz_sklearn_visualisations.ipynb) ファイルをもとに修正したところ、実際に出力ができるようになりました。
dtreevizのimportの仕方・メソッドの呼び出し方が異なっておりました。

**解決後のソースコード:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import japanize_matplotlib
#import pydot

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics, tree

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('ds1.csv'))
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[0])
df.head()

Col_x=["B_sub","ni_f","rcv_f","s","political","age"]
df_x = df[Col_x]
df_y = df["inf1b"]

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, random_state=1, test_size=0.15)

# モデルの作成
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3) 

# モデルの学習
clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

# 評価
clf.score(train_x, train_y)

clf.score(test_x, test_y)

# ライブラリのインポート
import dtreeviz

viz = dtreeviz.model(clf, 
                     X_train=df_x,
                     y_train=df['inf1b'],
                     feature_names = df_x.columns,
                     target_name='Media usage frequency',
                     class_names=["don't use much","Neither","use much"]
               )

viz.view()
```

Answer (score 0):

詳しく見れていませんが、TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptableはintが添字指定不可という意味なので、df_y[0]が原因なのでは？

Comment: 上記のコードの前に以下のコードを書いてあります。

`Col_x = ['B_sub','ni_f','rcv_f','s','political','age']
df_x=df[Col_x]
df_y = [df['inf1b'],df['inf2b'],df['inf3b'],df['inf4b']]`
このリストの１つ目の要素を指すようにしたかったのですが、

Comment: df_y[0]をdf['inf1b']に変更しても同じエラーが出ました。